# sshd not responding to port forwarded connection request

Tags: ssh, port-forwarding

I'm setting up port forwarding on a SonicWall NSA 220 router, for port 22.  It appears that the router is forwarding TCP packets as it should.  However, Wireshark running on the server shows that my server's sshd is ignoring these ssh connection requests and is not responding: it doesn't even attempt to send any packets back.

I can ssh directly to the server over the same ethernet interface (from another system on the LAN) just fine.  It's only the forwarded packets from the WAN side that receive no response.

So it seems that the culprit might be sshd: for some reason it is ignoring the forwarded packets.

The server is running RHEL 6.  The firewall is disabled.

Any ideas why sshd is ignoring the forwarded connection requests?  Or is the router to blame?

The following is tcpdump output (I'm using port 30002 here, but it's the same as port 22).  The server's IP address is 192.168.8.33.

```
08:52:12.350492 IP 192.168.1.32.52205 > 192.168.8.33.30002: Flags [S], seq 2460054041, win 14600, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 453857378 ecr 0,nop,wscale 6], length 0
08:52:13.347513 IP 192.168.1.32.52205 > 192.168.8.33.30002: Flags [S], seq 2460054041, win 14600, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 453857628 ecr 0,nop,wscale 6], length 0
08:52:15.351529 IP 192.168.1.32.52205 > 192.168.8.33.30002: Flags [S], seq 2460054041, win 14600, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 453858129 ecr 0,nop,wscale 6], length 0
08:52:19.363565 IP 192.168.1.32.52205 > 192.168.8.33.30002: Flags [S], seq 2460054041, win 14600, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 453859132 ecr 0,nop,wscale 6], length 0
```

Here is the tcpdump output when I ssh from the LAN, which is successful:

```
08:50:41.844945 IP 192.168.8.253.55442 > 192.168.8.33.30002: Flags [S], seq 2514711830, win 14600, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 4294948065 ecr 0,nop,wscale 6], length 0
08:50:41.844983 IP 192.168.8.33.30002 > 192.168.8.253.55442: Flags [S.], seq 2291827547, ack 2514711831, win 14480, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 6807100 ecr 4294948065,nop,wscale 7], length 0
08:50:41.845290 IP 192.168.8.253.55442 > 192.168.8.33.30002: Flags [.], ack 1, win 229, options [nop,nop,TS val 4294948065 ecr 6807100], length 0
etc....
```

Here is my sshd_config on the server:

```
sudo grep ^[^'#'] /etc/ssh/sshd_config
Port 22
Port 30002
Protocol 2
SyslogFacility AUTHPRIV
PasswordAuthentication yes
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
GSSAPIAuthentication yes
GSSAPICleanupCredentials yes
UsePAM yes
AcceptEnv LANG LC_CTYPE LC_NUMERIC LC_TIME LC_COLLATE LC_MONETARY LC_MESSAGES
AcceptEnv LC_PAPER LC_NAME LC_ADDRESS LC_TELEPHONE LC_MEASUREMENT
AcceptEnv LC_IDENTIFICATION LC_ALL LANGUAGE
AcceptEnv XMODIFIERS
X11Forwarding yes
Subsystem   sftp    /usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server
```

Here is iptables:

```
sudo iptables -L -n -v
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 5350 packets, 314K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 2121 packets, 14M bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

Comment: Can you cut-and-paste a few lines of `tcpdump` output from the server showing a SYN packet coming in on port 22, and nothing going back out?

Comment: I updated with tcpdump output.

Comment: Do ssh through the router with verbosity `ssh -v` `ssh -vv` `ssh -vvv` and see if there's any obvious error.  
  
Also what's the server's sshd configuration ( `grep ^[^'#'] /etc/ssh/sshd_config` )

Comment: If he doesn't even get a SYN-ACK packet back, `ssh -vvv` on the client side isn't going to reveal anything except `Connection timed out`.  David, forgive the question, but can you prove that the firewall is disabled by cutting-and-pasteing the output of `iptables -L -n -v` into your question?

Comment: Run ssh server in debug mode `sshd -d` and see if in the forwarding case the request reaches the ssh server or not (you should see `log: Connection from 192.168.1.32`), this will narrow down the issue in either filtering before reaching sshd or sshd server itself.  
  
(Also for completeness you may want to check the other fw rules other than the default that won't show up with `iptables -L` : `iptables -t nat -L` , `iptables -t mangle -L` , `iptables -t raw -L` )

Comment: Good point.  When running sshd -d, it is completely quiet when I try to ssh from the WAN.  This makes sense, because tcpdump showed that there isn't even an ACK on the packet.  So somehow the packets are being intercepted before reaching sshd.  I realized I hadn't completely disabled the firewall.  Now it really is disabled, but the result is the same.  All the iptables -t commands show ACCEPT for the policy.

Comment: Check the kernel log for any messages about packet being dropped - bad checksums maybe?

Comment: I don't see any messages in dmesg, /var/log/messages, /var/log/secure, or anything else in /var/log.

Comment: So it's a purely a networking issue, can you create any type of two-way communication between router and server? (starting with ping, using nc, any tcp protocol?)

Comment: Does the server have a route toward the client (192.168.1.32) in its routing table?

Comment: Ping works from the router to the server (I'll have to think about how to test tcp).  The server can ssh to the client (192.168.1.32).

Comment: The SonicWall router's WAN network is 192.168.1.*.  The LAN network is 192.168.8.*.  The server is 192.168.8.33.  The client I am trying to connect from is 192.168.1.32.

Comment: (deleted comment confusing 1/8).  
  
Then as Wumpus suggested the issue may be that hosts in the .8 netowrk (like server) don't know how to go to the .1 network (WAN clients), can you ping for example 192.168.1.32 from 192.168.8.33?

Comment: Yes, the server *can* get to the 192.168.1.* network: both ping and ssh work in that direction, from LAN to WAN.

Comment: If sshd service doesn't get the WAN client requests then there's a netowrk issue as we said before. If you can have a fine ssh session starting from server towards client then networking setup for bith or them are fine (barring weird firewall configuration but there's no fw in the server, check client just in case).  

"When you have eliminated the impossible, whatever remains, however improbable, must be the truth.", unless I've missed something then the problem is in what's left, the SonicWall router.

Comment: Either that or the OS.  Thanks very much for taking the time to help.  If I figure this out, I'll post it.

Comment: From what I understand if you review the relevant rules in the router, they should be the same for the "1" and the "8" network. Not sure what you mean by the OS as possible culprit. Also if you say what you want to accomplish in general maybe we can help in some other way, for example I'm not sure why you would want to use port forwarding (tcp:port) for ssh when you can just do ip routing, unless you want to do filtering in the SonicWall. Do post if you found out about the issue so I can go to sleep ;-)

Comment: LinuxDevOps, you can see what it was by my answer below (and that all evidence points to me being an idiot).  Thanks again for taking the time.

Comment: no problem, we were kind of on the right way in the sense there was a routing issue in the server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work finally.  I forgot that my server has two network interfaces, and both were connected: one to the router's LAN network, and one to the WAN network.

To explain: the router's WAN is 192.168.8.*.  The router's LAN is 192.168.1.*.  The server is 192.168.8.32, and the client is 192.168.1.33.

When I disconnected the server from the router's WAN network, all of a sudden it all worked.  I think RHEL on the server must have been confused by the two routes to the client 192.168.1.33.